Grails 6 on Tomcat 9 gives "The response object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade" after running fine for 2-3 hours
I have a grails 6 application, built using gradlew war and deployed on Tomcat 9 (AWS).
The application was converted from Grails 2.5.6, with a fresh build.
With the change to grails 6, I converted from using <g:remoteFunction> on the gsps to using ajax calls.
Locally, and for 2-3 hrs in production after the application server is started, the ajax calls run successfully, and the app behaves as expected.
However, after this time, unless the app server is restarted, I get a rash of these errors below, and the users then struggle with disappearing elements that would be updated by the ajax return results.
My suspicion is that the spring security session expires, and something strange is going on when the authenticationfilter(s), or other filters, maybe exception/error handling fire. If there is an exception within the ajax call (controller or service exception) I would not expect the ErrorPageFilter to be called (as I want to handle the exception, and return a 503 or other "bad" response to Ajax, complete with an error that is usefult to the user (or to me).
I have tried:
Increasing the spring session timeout to 8 hours in aaplication.yaml:
spring:
session:
timeout: 28800
Removing logging of the login time against the User record from grails.plugin.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent
Catching ALL exceptions in the controller method(s) called by Ajax (the only one caught is the "ControllerExecutionException"):
  @Transactional

    def theAjaxMethod() {
        log.error "ajax params ${params} for theAjaxMethod ${getPrincipal()?.username}"
        if (check_logged_in()) {
            try {
             
                   // do stuff including update the db, 
                  // some methods call a service, 
                 //some do direct domainObject.save flush:true failOnError:true 
                 // then render the template piece for the return to Ajax.
                    render template: '/folder/template', model: [// model stuff for template here//]
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (ex instanceof ControllerExecutionException) {
                    log.error "ajax  Caught a ControllerExecutionException in method (the method) logged in user is ${getPrincipal()?.username}"
                } else {
                    def errorForDisplay = "ajax addInvoiceDetail :  error: ${ex}, params: ${params} "
                    log.error "****** ajaxController errros!! ${errorForDisplay}"
                    render(status: 503, text: errorForDisplay)
                }

            }
        } else {
            log.error "Not logged in when calling add invoice Detail"
            render(status: 503, text: notLoggedInError)
        }
    }

Any help with debugging this further would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure there is some exception happening underneath, but untill I can see what it is, I have no way to be able to handle it and fix it.
Regards
Brigette
Here is the full stacktrace of a recent error:
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: 2024-11-04 14:25:37.196 ERROR --- [io-8080-exec-12] StackTrace                               : Full Stack Trace:
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The response object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkFacade(ResponseFacade.java:504)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.isCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:270)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setContentType(ResponseFacade.java:213)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setContentType(ServletResponseWrapper.java:134)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setContentType(ServletResponseWrapper.java:134)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setContentType(ServletResponseWrapper.java:134)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setContentType(ServletResponseWrapper.java:134)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.taglib.encoder.WebOutputContextLookup$WebOutputContext.setContentType(WebOutputContextLookup.
java:130)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.gsp.GroovyPageWritable.doWriteTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:124)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.gsp.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:82)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderTemplate(GroovyPageView.java:76)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:71)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:55)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper.renderViewForTemplate(ResponseRenderer.groo
vy:615)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper.render(ResponseRenderer.groovy:354)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper$render$3.call(Unknown Source)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at com.hailsystem.AjaxController.render(AjaxController.groovy)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$render$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at com.hailsystem.AjaxController.$tt__detailChanged(AjaxController.groovy:358)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor893.invoke(Unknown Source)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1029)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1012)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:101)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at com.hailsystem.AjaxController$_detailChanged_closure5.doCall(AjaxController.groovy)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor892.invoke(Unknown Source)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:274)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at com.hailsystem.AjaxController.detailChanged(AjaxController.groovy)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$MethodHandleInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:22
3)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor
.java:115)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityIntercept
or.java:81)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:
122)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:
116)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequest
ContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenti
cationFilter.groovy:54)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberM
eAuthenticationFilter.java:106)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberM
eAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContext
HolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuth
enticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuth
enticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groo
vy:64)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenc
eFilter.java:112)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenc
eFilter.java:82)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilte
r.java:96)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:761)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:388)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:936)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
Nov  4 04:25:37 ip-172-31-24-38 server[2083867]: #011at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

What exact version of Tomcat is being used? We also saw this with Tomcat 9.0.93 and a Grails 4 application.
In our research we found a couple of potential changelog entries that were relevant:

Correct regressions in the refactoring that added recycling of the coyote request and response to the HTTP/2 processing. (markt)
Update: The system property org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES will now default to true if not specified, which will in turn set the default value for the discardFacades connector attribute, thus causing facade objects to be discarded by default. (remm)

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html
The RECYCLE_FACADES system property might be able to mitigate this but I haven't tested it. We used Tomcat 9.0.86 and moved on for now.

thank you so much for this! I was aware of issues with Tomcat 10, but you have pointed out the exact change that occured in Tomcat 9.  Currently using Tomcat 9 on AWS, which is Tomcat 9.0.91, which DOES have the problem. Adding the org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES=false to the Environment Variables in the Elastic Beanstalk config appears to have resolved the issue.
